# PHP подсчитать и записать в массив кол-во ежедневных публикаций за месяц

Tags: php, sql, массивы

**Задача**: нужно подсчитать и записать в массив кол-во ежедневных публикаций за месяц, если публикации в этот день небыло вписать 0-ль. 
Есть таблица *info* с столбцами *info_id*, *info_date_start* (формат DATA), *info_text* и др. 
**В чем сложность**: есть дни когда публикаций нет и когда вывожу циклом в массив значения, то сами значения "плывут". 
**Прим.:** в таблице есть записи 3-го, 10-го, 12-го и 20-го числа. Выводим значения в массив и получаем

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "32"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Не понятно за какие дни данные. И как ставить 0-ль там где данных нет.
Сам код:

```
  $sql2 = 'SELECT count(info_date_start) FROM info';
  $sql2 .= ' WHERE MONTH(info_date_start) = MONTH(NOW())';
  $sql2 .= ' AND YEAR(info_date_start) = YEAR(NOW())';
  $sql2 .= ' GROUP BY DAY(info_date_start)'; 
  $result2 = $connect->query($sql2);  
  $daysarr = NULL;     
  while($count2 = $result2->fetch_array()) {
        $count2 = $count2[0];
        $daysarr[] = $count2;
  }
```

P.S. Sql запрос объединяю конкатенацией так как в дальнейшем добавяться условия вывода (фильтр) по месяцам и году. 
**Вопрос**: как правильно вписать данные в масссив, чтобы в дни когда нет записей указывать 0-ль либо как по другому решить данную задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нам понадобится служебная таблица с порядковыми номерами от 1 до 31 (делаем до 32 для удобства вставки):

```
create table seqnum(X int not null, primary key(X));
insert into seqnum values(1),(2),(3),(4);
insert into seqnum select X+4 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select X+8 from seqnum;
insert into seqnum select X+16 from seqnum;
```

Для получения данных за текущий месяц выбираем из seqnum "опорные" порядковые номера, до последнего дня месяца и с помощью `left join` клеим к ним нашу выборку:

```
select S.x, coalesce(A.cnt,0) as cnt
  from seqnum S
  left join (
    select day(info_date_start) as d,count(1) cnt
      from info
     where info_date_start between extract(YEAR_MONTH from now())*100+1
                               and last_day(now())
     group by day(info_date_start)
  ) A on A.d=S.x
  where S.x<=day(last_day(now()))
  order by S.x
```

Получаем две колонки: номер дня и количество за этот день или 0. первую можете выбросить если она вам мешает.

Обратите внимание на способ выборки записей за месяц. Поиск по интервалу дат гораздо эффективнее, чем применение функций year и month к колонке из таблицы. Хотя бы потому, что функции будут отрабатывать для каждой записи, а начальная и конечная дата месяца будет вычислена один раз. И если по колонке даты сделать индекс то поиск будет проходить гораздо быстрее, а применение функций сделают использование индекса невозможным.